wpa_supplicant fails to connect with some routers
I have a Yocto Linux device equipped with a Laird 450-0152r wifi module. When the system boots, a systemd service creates an access point using the following script:
#!/bin/bash
modprobe brcmfmac
iw dev wlan0 interface add wlan1 type __ap
ifconfig wlan1 192.168.3.1 up 
udhcpd /etc/udhcpd.conf
hostapd /etc/myhostapd.conf 

At a certain time a python script may stop the access point service and connect to a wifi using the following commands:
subprocess.call(['systemctl', 'stop', 'access_point'])  
subprocess.call(['killall', 'wpa_supplicant'])
subprocess.call(['ifconfig', 'wlan0', 'up'])
subprocess.call(['iw', 'wlan0', 'set', 'power_save', 'off'])            
            
wc_path = WIFI_CREDENTIALS_PATH # path to my conf file generated with wpa_passphrase    
            
subprocess.call(['wpa_supplicant', '-c', wc_path, 
                '-i', 'wlan0', '-B', '-ddd'],
                stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
            
time.sleep(4)
subprocess.call(['udhcpc', '-i', 'wlan0', '-b'],
            stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

This works fine but there are some places (i.e. some routers) where wpa_supplicant often fails to connect. The wpa_supplicant log is not very informative (I don't see any error message). The kernel shows some warnings but I'm not sure they are relevant and I don't know if they are always displayed:

[   91.642083] ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_run_escan: error (-52)
[   91.647486] ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_cfg80211_scan: scan error (-52)

My question is: how can I diagnose the problem that prevents wpa_supplicant to connect? Unfortunately I don't have access to the router where this problem occurs more frequently.
Additional info:

MAC address randomization is disabled
Power saving does not seem to be relevant
The driver is brcmfmac43430
NetworkManager is not available

Output of iw dev wlan0 info:
Interface wlan0
    ifindex 2
    wdev 0x1
    addr 00:25:ca:6b:d3:e5
    ssid SR09142
    type managed
    wiphy 0
    channel 1 (2412 MHz), width: 20 MHz, center1: 2412 MHz
    txpower 31.00 dBm

